# url including query string, redirect 301 from .htaccess fail

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I would like to redirect

- https://www.example.com/aboutus/details.php?target=indonesia

to

- https://www.example.com/about-us

I tried to redirect as follow but it always lead me to 404 page

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
 RewriteRule ^aboutus/details\.php /about-us [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Also I tried `Redirect 301` as follow but also lead me to 404 not found page

```
Redirect 301 /aboutus/details.php?target=indonesia   https://www.example.com/about-us
```

Any idea about this one? I was finding this problem for almost 2 days :(
And i am using Joomla !

Comment: Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: Same location with "administrator" Folder and "Template" Folder. Sorry to say that i am quite new with joomla and htaccess config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match against the query string then redirect the request to remove those query strings using **?** :

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /aboutus/details\.php\?target=indonesia [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /about-us? [L,R]
 RewriteRule ^about-us/?$ /aboutus/details.php?target=indonesia [NC,L]
```

Comment: Same Problem ! Still landing to 404 page !

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: Worst Bro ! Leads me internal server error and the whole site down !

Comment: Yes, perhaps your apache version is bellow 2.4 , this works on apache 2.4. Dont worry i will updated the rule.

Comment: Oh ya, i checked from ssh and show me as follow
"Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)"

Comment: :( Same problem 404 :(

Comment: Try clering your browser cache

Comment: Same bro .. landing 404 page